# Retornar Json com dados relacionados - Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

Estou criando uma API REST porem esbarrei nessa questão na qual não consigo imaginar uma solução.

Em meu banco de dados eu tenho 2 tabelas;

Tabela 1 - Dados gerais do produto tais como nome, código, sku e descrição

Tabela 2 - Códigos variaveis do produto.

Tabela 3 - Imagens dos produtos

Por exemplo;
Produto X contem os tamanhos 1,2,3 e 2 imagens (estes tamanhos e imagens estao em tabelas separadas da tabela 1).

Como eu faria para retornar um json com os dados relacionados entre as tabelas?
Atualmente eu só consegui retornar um "`all`" da tabela 1, qual seria a logica aplicada nessa situação para que eu retorne um json com o produto 1 e as variações do mesmo?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, as tres tabelas tem em comum o `idProduto` correto? Poderia dar um exemplo dos dados de cada tabelas para o `idProduto : 1`?

Comment: Tentou alguns joins? ou mapear os models?

Comment: Tabela-1 = 1:1, Tabela-2 = 1:N, tabela3 = 1:N?

Comment: Eu fiz um JOIN na minha query e depois trato tudo normalmente com as funções JSON do PHP. Eu faria o que @rray disse: tenta JOIN. Eu precisei criar um JSON para gerar uma tabela com o plugin jQuery jTable, então eu fiz um JOIN, que retorna uma view com a junção de várias tabelas como se fossem uma, o que é indiferente pro PHP que gerar a JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui encontrar a solução [neste tópico.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600013/how-to-return-a-json-response-based-on-database-relationship-using-eloquent)

Apos criar o relacionamento tanto nos controller, models e migrations;

Basicamente o que deve ser feito para buscar os dados relacionados é:

```
$dados = Post::with('Comments')->get();
return response()->json($dados);
```

> Levando em consideração a relação oneToMany

Comment: Marque como resolvida ;)